# installed python opencv 2.4.11 but only in the system it says I installed only 2.4.8

Tags: python, opencv, version

I followed this link and installed opencv 2.4.11. However when I printed the current opencv version it says it is 2.4.8. Could anyone tell me what went wrong please? Thanks.

https://gist.github.com/dynamicguy/3d1fce8dae65e765f7c4

P.s. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. The command to check the current version of opencv is

import cv2

print cv2.__version__

As kindly suggested by   PraveenPalanisamy I am posting my result of running the command

ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep opencv

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1483006 Jul 26 21:33 libopencv_calib3d.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1850138 Jul 26 21:45 libopencv_contrib.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4811636 Jul 26 21:26 libopencv_core.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1420516 Jul 26 21:29 libopencv_features2d.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1100238 Jul 26 21:26 libopencv_flann.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   863666 Jul 26 21:39 libopencv_gpu.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1258032 Jul 26 21:28 libopencv_highgui.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4363758 Jul 26 21:28 libopencv_imgproc.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2400896 Jul 26 21:37 libopencv_legacy.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1051714 Jul 26 21:35 libopencv_ml.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   411916 Jul 26 21:44 libopencv_nonfree.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   954904 Jul 26 21:38 libopencv_objdetect.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3269948 Jul 26 21:41 libopencv_ocl.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   187250 Jul 26 21:38 libopencv_photo.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   960120 Jul 26 21:46 libopencv_stitching.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   543080 Jul 26 21:47 libopencv_superres.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1779168 Jul 26 21:29 libopencv_ts.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   625806 Jul 26 21:29 libopencv_video.a

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   508350 Jul 26 21:47 libopencv_videostab.a

Comment: how did you install?

Comment: I installed following the instruction here

https://gist.github.com/dynamicguy/3d1fce8dae65e765f7c4

Comment: Did you run `sudo make install` at the end?

Comment: yes I did, it took 30 mins to execute the command so I think it is done "properly"

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep opencv`

Comment: Hi sorry I could not post pictures as I need more reputations but I have copied the text of the output in my original question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting the output. I have updated my answer to address your issue specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
From the output of your `ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep opencv` seems like static OpenCV libraries were built. Due to the `-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` flag on line 21 in the instructions. You could just remove `-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` from that line and go over the installation process again for a clean install or simply run the following 3 lines with your current status:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D BUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=ON -D INSTALL_TO_MANGLED_PATHS=ON -D INSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON -D INSTALL_TESTS=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON -D WITH_IMAGEIO=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON ..
make all -j4 # 4 cores
sudo make install
```

.That should build shared OpenCV libraries and hopefully it'll solve your problem. If for some reason you still get the same error, then use the remaining of my answer (below) to fix the problem:

For some reason, the python module **cv2** that you are importing is from OpenCV 2.4.8 which got installed when you ran the 11th line from the instructions that you followed ( Specifically this command: `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev`).
The 23rd line in the instructions that you followed (`sudo make install`) should have installed the OpenCV2.4.11 as the default OpenCV library. Which can be verified by looking at the output of `ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep opencv`.
Instead of looking at many lines of the output, you can make it simpler by looking at the output of `ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep opencv_core`.
You should see something like:

```
libopencv_core.so -> libopencv_core.so.2.4
libopencv_core.so.2.4 -> libopencv_core.so.2.4.11
libopencv_core.so.2.4.11
libopencv_core.so.2.4.8
```

**Case 1**:
If you see the above lines exactly as they are, then it means your `sudo make install` worked and so, the default OpenCV library version (pointed by `pkg-config --libs opencv`) is **2.4.11**. Then you need to look into the python modules path to see why your **cv2** python module is from OpenCV 2.4.8 and not the one from OpenCV2.4.11. To do this, you can run `ls -l /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ | grep cv` to make sure you see **cv2** and **cv** listed (see the lines below for example)

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ | grep cv
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff  1638779 Jul 13 18:29 cv2.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff       21 Feb 25 07:10 cv.py
```

and then,look at the output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so | grep opencv` it should look something like :

```
libopencv_core.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4 (0x00007f0df24e2000)
libopencv_flann.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.4 (0x00007f0df226e000)
libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 (0x00007f0df1d7f000)
libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 (0x00007f0df1ad2000)
```

Look at the first line of your output carefully: (for example)
`libopencv_core.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4`. This the library that the python module/wrapper uses. This should be pointing to **libopencv_core.so.2.4.11** and not **libopencv_core.so.2.4.8**. You can verify where `libopencv_core.so.2.4` is pointing to with the same command used before (`ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep opencv`).

**Case 2:**
The output of `ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep opencv_core` is something like:

```
libopencv_core.so -> libopencv_core.so.2.4
libopencv_core.so.2.4 -> libopencv_core.so.2.4.8
```

Which means the `sudo make install` that you ran while building OpenCV2.4.11 didn't work for some reason. Then you can two choices:

**Choice 1**:
Run `make && sudo make install` from `opencv-2.4.11/release` directory. Then follow the steps above to see if you see this line **libopencv_core.so.2.4 -> libopencv_core.so.2.4.11**. If you see it then, `import cv2 print cv2.version` should print 2.4.11.

**Choice 2**
If you see the file `libopencv_core.so.2.4.11` existing in your `/usr/local/lib` directory, then you can just create a **symlink** to make the default OpenCV library files point to version 2.4.11 (which is automatically done when you run `sudo make install` from the OpenCV build directory)

Comment: omg thx for solving my problem! It was solved using the three lines of code give by you at the very beginning of the answer lol but thanks for your effort for producing such a detailed explanation.  I just started ubuntu yesterday and honestly I have no idea how you have fixed the problem but thanks again for your effort!

Comment: Glad that I could help you fix the problem.